# CKEDITOR title&body (simplebox example) widget : select title text and remove

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, widget, ckeditor

I'm using the simplebox widget demonstrated here: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/simplebox.html

when i try to select all title text using CTRL+A and Backspace, title gets removed and body stays in place, but when I try to select title using the mouse double left-click, the title gets removed, but part of the content ('Foo bar.' in this example) goes up to the title div.

**Title and body widget:**
[image: Title and body widget]
**Select all text using mouse double left-click**
[image: Select all text using mouse double left-click]
**And Backspace to remove:**
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I'm running Linux-Debian on my laptop, it's not working in Chrome (Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)), but working fine in Iceweasel. I also tried it on my colleague's Chrome/Firefox who's running Windows on his laptop, same, working in Firefox but not in Chrome. what version of Chrome do you have?

Comment: What is your environment, OS and browser? I cannot seem to reproduce it on Win8, neither in Chrome, Firefox or IE11.

Comment: It's strange. I'm running Linux-Debian on my laptop, it's not working in Chrome (Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)), but working fine in Iceweasel. I also tried it on my colleague's Chrome/Firefox who's running Windows on his laptop, same, working in Firefox but not in Chrome. what version of Chrome do you have?

Comment: What is the question that you want to ask?

Comment: I reported http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14353 and http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14354.

Comment: Yes exactly, this was a bug report, thank you for reporting. I think it's important to mention that I'm using version: 4.4.7, revision:"3a35b3d".